# FastText most_similar doesn't return complete match

Tags: python, nlp, data-science, fasttext

I do know there is a word "cat" and the word "cats" in my vocabulary.

**Example 1:**

```
model.wv.most_similar("cat")
```

This returns [ ("cats", 0.83...), ("wild", 0.79...), ... ]. There is no ("cat", 1.0) on the top of result.

**Example 2:**

```
model.wv.most_similar("cats")
```

This returns [ ("cat", 0.85...), ("wild", 0.77...), ... ]. There is no ("cats", 1.0) on the top of result.

**Question:** is there a way to get complete match on the top of result if it is? Or to check complete match with other method... Mayby I don't understand something. Anyway, help needed.

Comment: Cuz it's obvious that a word is similar to itself, so it is showing the rest of the similar words in the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use AnnoyIndexer and you will have the most similar element as well

```
   from gensim.models import Word2Vec, KeyedVectors
   from gensim.models.word2vec import Text8Corpus


   params = {
     'alpha': 0.05,
     'size': 100,
     'window': 5,
     'iter': 5,
     'min_count': 5,
     'sample': 1e-4,
     'sg': 1,
     'hs': 0,
     'negative': 5
  }
  model = Word2Vec(Text8Corpus(text8_path), **params)
  print(model)
  from gensim.similarities.index import AnnoyIndexer

  annoy_index = AnnoyIndexer(model, 100)

  vector = model.wv["cats"]

  approximate_neighbors = model.wv.most_similar([vector], topn=11, 
  indexer=annoy_index)

  print("Approximate Neighbors")
  for neighbor in approximate_neighbors:
     print(neighbor)
```

OUTPUT SNIPPET:

```
Approximate Neighbors
('cats', 1.0)
('wallabies', 0.6341749131679535)
('coyotes', 0.6311245858669281)
('kangaroos', 0.6296325325965881)
('felines', 0.6287126243114471)
('squirrels', 0.6270308494567871)
('dogs', 0.6266725659370422)
('leopards', 0.6130028069019318)
('omnivores', 0.6129975318908691)
('koalas', 0.612080842256546)
('microbats', 0.6070675551891327)
```

Do let me me if you are stuck somewhere..:)